# SQL Results show up in both queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to return results where people have signed a particular survey. However ''m having issues returning survey answers when they have previously answered Survey 1 in the past and show in both Survey 1 & Survey 2.

How do i ensure survey answers only appear once by selecting the most recent survey results so that they do not show in both Surveys?

The results in italics represent a duplicate record for a store which has answered both surveys but i only want the most recently answered survey to appear. In this instance they should only appear in Survey 1 as it is most recent

**CODE**

```
go
use [database]

--Select Outlets that have answers to Survey 1
(select distinct activityanswers.CustomerNumber as Outlet, 'Survey 1' as 
'Survey Program', max(answereddate) as 'Last Answered Date'
from dbo.activityanswers
where activityid in (select id from activitys where ActivityGroupId = 
'1061293')              
group by customernumber
)


--Select Outlets that have answers to Survey 2
(select distinct activityanswers.CustomerNumber as Outlet, 'Survey 2' as 
'Survey Program', max(answereddate) as 'Last Answered Date'
from dbo.activityanswers
where activityid in (select id from activitys where ActivityGroupId = 
'1061294')                                                              
group by customernumber
)
```

**Survey 1 RESULTS**

```
Store   Survey      AnswerTime
1285939 Survey 1    2018-08-27 10:13:57.000
1348372 Survey 1    2018-08-27 09:21:18.000
2142522 Survey 1    2018-08-27 15:26:29.000
2147380   Survey 1    2018-08-24 22:26:49.000
```

**Survey 2 RESULTS**

```
Store   Survey      AnswerTime
2147380   Survey 2    2018-08-24 21:58:59.000
2641188 Survey 2    2018-08-27 11:39:31.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result with a Single SQL Statement. Try using Row_Number or Rank Function.

Something like this might work

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    RN =ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ANS.CustomerNumber ORDER BY ANS.answereddate DESC,
ACT.ActivityGroupId ASC),
    ANS.CustomerNumber as Outlet, 
    CASE ACT.ActivityGroupId
        WHEN '1061293' THEN 'Survey 1' 
        ELSE 'Survey 2' END as 'Survey Program', 
    ANS.answereddate as 'Last Answered Date'
    FROM dbo.ActivityAnswers ANS
        INNER JOIN Activitys ACT
            ON ANS.activityid = ACT.ID
        WHERE ACT.ActivityGroupId IN 
            (
                '1061293',
                '1061294'
            )
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
        WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should filter after grouping, try something like this:

```
select a.CustomerNumber as Outlet, a.Last_Answered_Date from (
select CustomerNumber, max(answereddate) as 'Last_Answered_Date'
from activityanswers 
group by customernumber) a
join activityanswers b on a.CustomerNumber = b.CustomerNumber and a. 
[Last_Answered_Date] = b.answereddate
where b.activityid in (select id from activitys where ActivityGroupId = '1061294')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking whether a particular customer has a newer answer or not (not exists subquery). That way, you can also eliminate the need to group by.

```
select
    CustomerNumber as Outlet, 
    'Survey 1' as 'Survey Program', 
    answereddate as 'Last Answered Date'
from dbo.activityanswers a
where activityid in (
    select id from activitys where ActivityGroupId = '1061293')
and not exists (
    select from dbo.activityanswers b 
    where b.CustomerNumber = a.CustomerNumber
    and b.answereddate > a.answereddate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a sub-query would serve your purpose !

```
SELECT 
  Outlet
, SurveyProgram
, LastAnsweredDate  
FROM (
SELECT
    ans.CustomerNumber  Outlet
,   CASE WHEN ActivityGroupId = '1061293' THEN 'Survey 1' ELSE 'Survey 2' END   SurveyProgram
,   answereddate LastAnsweredDate
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ans.CustomerNumber ORDER BY answereddate DESC) RN 
FROM 
    activityanswers ans
LEFT JOIN activitys act ON act.ID = ans.activityid AND ActivityGroupId IN('1061293', '1061294') 
GROUP BY 
    ans.CustomerNumber
) D
WHERE 
    RN = 1
```

I have replaced the `IN()` with a `LEFT JOIN` which is much better approach in your query. Also, from the query it will give you both Survey 1 and 2, so we used `ROW_NUMBER` to filter them. I ordered them in DESC, so the recent datetime will be at the top. So, getting the first row from each CustomerNumber will give you the recent records.  . This would give you more stretching flexibility in the query.